# How can i export a csv containing arabic letters?

Tags: r, csv

I want to export a dataframe to arabic language, I tried a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3792846/how-to-export-a-csv-in-utf-8-format) but it didn't work as my output seems different.here is a sample code:

```
k<-c("أحمد","محمد","محمود")
write.csv(k,"kk.csv",fileEncoding="utf8")
```

output is like this

```
"","x" "1","<U+0623><U+062D><U+0645><U+062F>"
```

And then with unknown cause -when i tried the example again- it became :

> "","x" "1","ÃÍãÏ"

Also R was viewing arabic letters correctly in the console but just after i tried the example is now view arabic letters like this "ÃÍãÏ"  What's wrong with me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13897520/5472462) where it may be R that cannot identify the characters but once the .csv is written it can be opened in a different software and viewed correctly.